# Fixed responsive menu hide after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a responsive fixed top menu that opens after clicking on the Menu icon. **Then I would like to hide it** after clicking on one of the menu items. Otherwise it covers part of the section that slides up.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');

    $(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).next("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
            $("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, nav .sub-menu").removeAttr("style");
            $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");
        }
    });

    $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
        if (event.target !== this)
        return;
            $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: can you share the html as well or a quick jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#whatever_you_click').change(function() {
$('#whatever_you_want_to_hide').hide();
});
```

Comment: This helped. I added: 
 $('.menu-item').click(function() {
 $('#menu-primary-menu').slideToggle();
 });
Thank you @jonmrich

Answer (score 2):

Without the relevant html or knowing which menu plugin you are using, can only best guess.

For example you may need both slideToggle and removeClass - it's not clear if removeClass is enough on its own

```
$(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
    if (event.target !== this)
        return;

    // This looks like it closes the .menu-item that contains the .sub-menu being opened 
    //- is this the right thing to do?
    $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
    });

    // find other .menu-items and .sub-menu items and close them
    $(this)
        .closest(".responsive-menu")
        .find(".menu-item")
        .not(this)
        .toggleClass("menu-open")
        .find(".sub-menu")
        .toggleClass("menu-open");
});
```

You'll probably want something similar for .sub-menu click